# Load image to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datareader

I have been trying to figure this out all day.  I am trying to load a GridView with data from SQL in 3 columns and then dynamically add an image to a 4th column.  The data from SQL loads fine but I can not get the images to load no matter what I do.  Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("StoredProc", myConnection1);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     if (reader["ServiceStatus"].ToString().ToLower() == "stopped")
     {
          ImageField status = new ImageField();
          status.HeaderText = "Status";
          status.Visible = true;
          GridView1.Columns.Add(status);
          status.DataAlternateTextFormatString = @"~/Images/Image.gif";
     }

     GridView1.DataSource = reader;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I have tried creating a data table and populating that and it still will not work.  I know there has to be an easy way to do this.  What am I missing?

EDIT:

I am using a TemplateField now and I am getting a default image to show up:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/greydot.jpg"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So how should I reference this ImageURL in my code behind in order to change that image?  The images are store in the solution not in SQL.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You probably need to set also the [DataImageUrlField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.dataimageurlfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to show any image at all and then set a format string in the **DataAlternateTextFormatString** ([MSDN usage example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.dataalternatetextformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

You can store the path in database or can give path to the respective Image dynamically. Like this:

```
ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ProductImage")
```

Comment: I have thought about doing that but this should be a dynamic gridview that display an image based on status.  I hate to have an entire table for just 3 images.  If I have no choice I will go down that route but there has to be another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void gvUserProfile_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow ) 
    {
        // set reference to current data record 
        // use IDataRecord if you bind to a DataReader, and DataRowView if you bind to a DataSet
        DataRowView dataRow = ( DataRowView ) e.Row.DataItem;
        string myflag = dataRow [ "yourColumnNameHere" ].ToString ( );
        if ( myflag == "0" ) 
        {
            // do something amusing here
        }
    }
}
```

2 - if you instantiate any new control on RowDataBound ( such as your ImageButton ), you have to add the instantiated control to the Controls collection of the cell. Something like

```
e.Row.Cells [ 0 ].Controls.Clear ( );
ImageButton img = new ImageButton ( );
img.ImageUrl = "~/images/editGray.gif";
e.Row.Cells [ 0 ].Controls.Add ( img );
```